# The stylesheet x was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Tags: heroku, mime-types, mern

I developed a `MERN` application where everything runs perfectly normal on `localhost`. Now I put my application live, `Heroku` for the `backend` and `Netlify` for the `frontend`, and when visting my home url `(https://bap-nmd-2020-2021.netlify.app/)` the page just stucks. Nothing is loaded and the code stops executing.

I used chrome and firefox dev edition to see what could be wrong. What I found where the following errors

In chrome dev tools:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

In Firefox dev edition:

```
The stylesheet https://bap-nmd-2020-2021.netlify.app/static/css/main.ab94b624.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'2.c23262ff.chunk.js:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'main.361ee52b.chunk.js:1
```

As I said, everything runs smooth on `localhost` without any problems so my `paths` to imported files should be ok. So I am totally clueless about what could be the issue here.

I've already read through some threads here concerning this issue but I could not found the same exact problem. Most of the people have wrong `paths` included in there `hrefs`, which is not the the case here I think.

Somebody has any idea please?

Thanks in advance!